# SignInAsync exiting before finishing stack/returning too quickly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Here's part ofmy Login method

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                //some logic to determine if a new user needs created with new program/password requirements
                            await SignInAsync(NewUser, false);  //this executes, but never comes back to do the line below this
                            if (OldUser.ResellerId.Equals(CurrentReseller.ResellerId))                  {
                                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                            }
                            return RedirectToCorrectReseller(NewUser);
}
```

Here's the call to the Async method that MVC 5 put in

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

when i step through this, it gets  to the last "}" and looks like it finishes the method, but the debugger stops, and goes back to the website as if it's logged in, when i select a new link, it does display the correct info as if they're logged in, but i can't redirect to where i want to after the sign in happens...any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This also happens if I remove the async calls, to this:

```
   private void SignIn(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent) {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Comment: do you know what Async and await does?

Comment: makes an async call to login and authenticate, but to my understanding, adding the await keyword should force the server to wait.  I didn't change anything that the original template did besides adding the if after the await SignInAsync, because right after that, it was returning to the local returnURl

Comment: your understanding of await is a little incorrect my friend. it doesn't force the server to wait or anything. Please read this carefully: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx

Comment: Okay, so what will make sure that the SignInAsync method executes before moving on to the if on the next line? and is this really the reason why it returns without coming back to the original calling method stack?

Comment: I also think your SignInAsync method is incomplete here (did you just post a snippet or the entire method itself?) I don't see you returning a Task

Comment: that SignInAsync method was put in by the MVC5 template.  i did not alter or change the method in any way.  So if it's like that, Microsoft must have left it out.

Comment: see if this helps you understand the differences in code: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for.  The stuff that is causing the issue is what MS already had in their template, I'm wondering if there is more than that.  the await keyword should wait for the process to complete before moving on in the method it was called from.

Comment: @brentlyjdavid, is the whole chain of your controller methods `async`, up to the root? Does your code use `.Result` or `.Wait` anywhere on the upper stack frame, by chance?

Comment: No, The only Async calls are with the sign in method, of that "Login" action.  Other than that, they're all normal calls, i don't know of any .Result or .Wait except for what MS put in as a "Var Result = UserManager.CreateAsync(...);" and then used it as "if (Result.Succeeded){...}"

Comment: As @Noseratio said, you need to go async all the way to the top. Your code doesn't seem to do so. You probably should be awaiting `UserManager.CreateAsync`.

Comment: Here are all the async calls in my methods.  var NewUser = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);   var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(NewUser, model.Password);   and await SignInAsync(NewUser, false);           all of these are called properly during the step through, except the sign in, which after reaching the last } in that method call, it exits all stacks and goes to the webpage as if it's finished everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that seemed to work for me on this was updating the Nuget packages for identity.  Must have been a random bug i came across. I have no other explanation.